# Generalized Levenshtein Distance Cython

Tags: cython

I have a reasonably fast Levenshtein Distance in cython, but it is much slower than the Levenshtein library for python.  Does anyone know why?  Thanks!

The first function is code for a distance function between strings x and y in the style of Levenshtein but with the additional tuning parameters d and e.  It is computed via dynamic programming.  The second function is a wrapper that computes a distance table for a large number of strings.

```
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef int distance(str x,str y,int d,int e):
    cdef int m = len(x) + 1
    cdef int n = len(y) + 1
    cdef int* M = <int*>malloc(m*n*sizeof(int))
    cdef int i = 0
    cdef int j = 0
    cdef int sub
    
    for ii in range(m):
        M[ii] = ii
    for jj in range(n):
        M[m*jj] = jj

    for j in range(n - 1):
        for i in range(m - 1):
            if x[i] == y[j]:
                sub = 0
            else:
                sub = d
            M[i + 1 + m*(j + 1)] = min(min(M[i + m*(j + 1)] + e,M[i + 1 + m*j] + e),M[i + m*j] + sub)

    out = M[m*n - 1]

    free(M)
    
    return out

def distance_table(np.ndarray X,int d,int e):
    M = len(X)
    D = np.zeros((M,M))
    cdef int i
    cdef int j
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(i):
            D[i,j] = distance(str(X[i]),str(X[j]),d,e)
        print(i)
    D = D + D.T
    return D
```

Comment: As a very quick improvement, you could add `@cython.boundcheck(False)` and `@cython.wraparound(False)` to `distance`. It'll speed up the string indexing slightly. Probably won't be a dramatic change

Comment: What happens if you replace python's min function with the C equivalent in the distance function?